# Measure how Straight/Smooth the Text Borders are Rendered in an Image

Tags: python, image, image-processing, text, signal-processing

I have two images:

[image]

[image]

I want to measure how straight/smooth the text borders are rendered.

First image is rendered perfectly straight, so it deserves a quality measure `1`. On the other hand, the second image is rendered with a lot of variant curves (rough in a way) that is why it deserves a quality measure less than `1`. How will I measure it using image processing or any Python function or any function written in other languages?

Clarification :

There are font styles that are rendered originally with straight strokes but there are also font styles that are rendered smoothly just like the cursive font styles. What I'm really after is to differentiate the text border surface roughness of the characters by giving it a quality measure.

I want to measure how straight/smooth the text borders are rendered in an image.
Inversely, it can also be said that I want to measure how rough the text borders are rendered in an image.

Comment: You say "smooth", but I think you mean to say "straight"?

Comment: @CrisLuengo -> Yes, I mean straight. Sorry

Comment: So that makes the answer below useless then? I suggest you edit your question to make it clear what you're after!

Comment: @CrisLuengo -> Ok I will clarify it . It can be straight or smooth.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know any python function, but I would:

1) Use `potrace` to trace the edges and convert them to bezier curves. Here's a vizualisation:
[image]

2) Then let's zoom to the top part of the `P` for example: 
[image]
You draw lines perpendicular to the curve for a finite length (let's say 100 pixels). You plot the color intensity (you can convert to HSI or HSV and use one of those channels, or just convert to grayscale and take the pixel value directly) over that line:

[image]
3) Then you calculate the standard deviation of the derivative. Small standard deviation means sharp edges, large standard deviation means blurry edges. For a perfect edge, the standard deviation would be zero.

4) For every edge were you drew a perpendicular line, you now have a "smoothness" value. You can then average all the smoothness values per edge, per letter, per word or per image, as you see fit. Also, the more perpendicular lines you draw, the more accurate your smoothness value, but the more computationally intensive.

Comment: The Web Content Accessibility Guidelines suggest converting to a linear scale (relative luminance) before measuring text-background contrast ratios.

Answer (score 4):

I would try something simple like creating a 'roughness' metric using a few functions from the opencv library, since it's easy to work with in Python (and C++, as well as other wrappers).

For example (without actual source, since I'm typing on my phone):

1. Preprocess to create binary images (many standard ways).
2. Use `cv2.findContours` to get outlines of the letters.
3. Use `cv2.arcLength` on each contour as denominators.
4. Use `cv2.approxPolyDP` to simplify each contour.
5. Use `cv2.arcLength` on each simplified contour as numerators.
6. Calculate ratios of simplified over full arc lengths.

In step 5, ratios closer to 1.0 require less simplification, so they're presumably less rough. Ratios closer to 0.0 require a lot of simplification, and are therefore probably very rough. Of course, you'll have to tweak the contour finding code to get appropriate outlines to work with, and you'll need to manage numerical precision to keep the math calculations meaningful, but hopefully the idea is clear enough.

OpenCV also has the useful functions `cv2.convexHull` and `cv2.convexityDefects` that you might find interesting in related work. However, they didn't seem appropriate for the letters here, since internal features on letters like M for example would be more challenging to address.

Speaking of rough things, I admit this algorithmic outline is incredibly rough! However, I hope it gives you a useful idea to try that seems straightforward to implement quickly to start getting quantitative feedback.

Comment: The trouble I faced in any contouring, vertex count approach was the susceptibility to resolution and scale. Image two cases of the same non-arc curvature at two differing resolutions; you are likely to produce two differing Step 6 ratios despite a constant "form". It becomes difficult therefore to compare image to image unless you can be sure that the characters have equivalent "DPI" and scale. I was toying with ways to normalize vertex based methods for this reason. Any ideas?

Comment: I agree! I intended to suggest the idea a starting point for a roughness metric based on further (missing) context not just raw ratios. Without doing letter ID it seemed good for tweaking in python using real test data. Vertex counting seems less robust to font letter variation. I'd want to factor res/scale (e.g. multipliers, curvature per length, ..) but I'd want to know problem critera first: clarify smooth/roughness, acceptable error, etc before going down a theoretical rabbit hole. I don't fully understand OP real use case but I hoped the simplification comparison concept worth mentioning.

Comment: I'm thinking the same lines exactly. I don't think there's enough detail in the question to provide a definitive "answer" or whether in fact fundamentally, calculating a "smoothness metric" that can be applied across render/print qualities, fonts, resolutions and scales is even feasible. Another line of thinking I exploded was to count "inflections" or number of CW/CCW  inversion on the dot product of successive contour segments (if that makes sense?) Perhaps you had some thoughts there or could explorer the idea on simplified contours?

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood I had a similar CW/CCW idea but chose my way instead to address OP desire that the first sample attain a quality measure of 1. Pure inflection counting penalizes letters that are perfectly smooth but change inflection as you traverse their perimeter (e.g. M or actually most letters). That's why I went with a simplification ratio idea to measure quality. I try to compare each actual letter with what it's "trying to be" (as estimated by approxPolyDP w/ good epsilon). So arc length shrinks as noisy inflections either direction get smoothed out, but larger scale shape remains.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood The "curvature per length" idea I mentioned in my original response to you was meant to indicate an inflection-direction-independent measure of curviness (inspired by topology) to weed out 'rapid' changes in inflection in either direction, while preserving the 'slower' curving sections. This seemed especially important, since OP mentioned dealing with curvy fonts. I've used this kind of curvature per length measure in a real project (scaled for resolution) to remove noise from rough contours detected via watershed, and it worked well for that application (RT 4k@60Hz).

Comment: Perhaps I didn't include the final comparative step in my answer so I see why you would of misunderstood my intention. I had thought that each character should be compared to its counter part individually, one to one, for exactly the penalty reason you have described. The quality measure 1 is arbitrary to the number of inflections for that specific character, e.g. from my data, if M scores 43 in the baseline, the test M quality is 5.42 as 233/43. The character "qualities" could be averaged for the word quality. [1 of 2]

Comment: With respect to the method it's self, it's certainly more an "approach" than it is a solution. If you'll see the comments to my own answer there is serious flaws on an inflections approach when applied to polyline contours, principally: Any straight but angled form will, being pixels, be a "staircase" of a given gradient containing many inflections, ultimately contributing to a lower score on a "smooth" character. This isn't a complete failure if applied character to character, however some regression/smoothing of the contours is need. Bezier inflections is the correct way to go imho. [2 of 2]

Answer (score 4):

One idea might be simply to get the average of the number of vertices per character in Python/OpenCV using cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE.

Since you have the same characters and you want to know how straight they are, the CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE measures only horizontal and vertical corner vertices. For your first image, there should be much fewer vertices than for your second image.

> CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE compresses horizontal, vertical, and diagonal
>   segments and leaves only their end points. For example, an up-right
>   rectangular contour is encoded with 4 points.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('lemper1.png')
#img = cv2.imread('lemper2.png')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# invert
thresh = 255 - thresh

# get contours and compute average number of vertices per character (contour)
result = img.copy()
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
num_contours = 0
sum = 0
for cntr in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(result, [cntr], 0, (0,0,255), 1)
    num_vertices = len(cntr)
    sum = sum + num_vertices
    num_contours = num_contours + 1

smoothness = (sum / num_contours)
print(smoothness)

# save resulting images
cv2.imwrite('lemper1_contours.png',result)
#cv2.imwrite('lemper2_contours.png',result)

# show thresh and result    
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("contours", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```
First image average number of vertices: 49.666666666666664

Second image average number of vertices: 179.14285714285714
```

**So smaller number of vertices means straighter characters.**

Comment: I also toyed with this idea, the trouble with it, at least in my testing, is the susceptibility to scale and resolution. Imagine for example a perfect, "smooth" circle or "O" in this case. At high resolution that curvature would result in many vertices despite being "smooth", and problematically, perhaps more than a "rough" lower resolution "O". I was considering ideas of somehow normalizing the vertex count by the aggregate contour length or other metric. What do you think?

Comment: My first though that I implement and then discarded was the divide the number of vertices by the perimeter so as to have a count per unit length as a means of normalizing for scale. Does that make more sense to you? The perimeter is measured by cv2.arcLength().

Comment: That was exactly my first though and I tried it unfortunately produce results failing the test cases. I "manually" summed the contour segments apposed rather than `.acrLength()` but the result was the same.

Answer (score 4):

### Preface

There's a few nice ideas presented here based around the properties of the character contours as polylines. Whilst there is some inherent flaws in this approach due to them being a function of resolution and scale, I would like to offer one further interruption of the same. **My algorithm is still susceptible** but it may offer a different perspective.

### Theory

The method I propose is to compare common characters by the number of inflections in their contours. In this context, what I mean by inflection, is a sign change between the cross products of successive polyline segments as vector. For example; consider a polyline contour of a circle, starting at the mid y coordinate and the x+ most coordinate. If we were to trace the polyline contour CW (clockwise) around the perimeter, each line segment would be incrementally a CW transform of the prior. If at any time a segment turned "away" or "outwards", this transform would be CCW (counter-clockwise) and the cross product will invert. A "rough" circle will therefore have inflections, a "perfect" or "smooth" circle will have none.

### Algorithm

The algorithm follows the steps below using the `Emgu.CV`. `C#` code below that:

1. The images are loaded and converted to binary by means of thresholding
2. The binary images then undergo contour detection and these contours are sort by their bounding box, left to right, so and their indices match the occurrence order of the character they contour.
3. Each contour is then re-pointed to an equal number of segments in order to normalize for scale and resolution differences between images/characters.
4. Each contour is "walked" and its number of inflections counted.

```cs
// [Some basic extensions are omitted for clarity] 
// Load the images
Image<Rgb, byte> baseLineImage = new Image<Rgb, byte>("BaseLine.png");
Image<Rgb, byte> testCaseImage = new Image<Rgb, byte>("TestCase.png");
// Convert them to Gray Scale
Image<Gray, byte> baseLineGray = baseLineImage.Convert<Gray, byte>();
Image<Gray, byte> testCaseGray = testCaseImage.Convert<Gray, byte>();
// Threshold the images to binary
Image<Gray, byte> baseLineBinary = baseLineGray.ThresholdBinaryInv(new Gray(100), new Gray(255));
Image<Gray, byte> testCaseBinary = testCaseGray.ThresholdBinaryInv(new Gray(100), new Gray(255));
// Some dilation required on the test image so that the characters are continuous
testCaseBinary = testCaseBinary.Dilate(3);

// Extract the the contours from the images to isolate the character profiles
// and sort them left to right so as the indicies match the character order
VectorOfVectorOfPoint baseLineContours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
Mat baseHierarchy = new Mat();
CvInvoke.FindContours(
    baseLineBinary,
    baseLineContours,
    baseHierarchy,
    RetrType.External,
    ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
var baseLineContoursList = baseLineContours.ToList();
baseLineContoursList.Sort(new ContourComparer());

VectorOfVectorOfPoint testCaseContours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
Mat testHierarchy = new Mat();
CvInvoke.FindContours(
    testCaseBinary,
    testCaseContours,
    testHierarchy,
    RetrType.External,
    ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
var testCaseContoursList = testCaseContours.ToList();
testCaseContoursList.Sort(new ContourComparer());

var baseLineRepointedContours = RepointContours(baseLineContoursList, 50);
var testCaseRepointedContours = RepointContours(testCaseContoursList, 50);

var baseLineInflectionCounts = GetContourInflections(baseLineRepointedContours);
var testCaseInflectionCounts = GetContourInflections(testCaseRepointedContours);
```

### Inflection Detection/Counting

```cs
static List<List<Point>> GetContourInflections(List<VectorOfPoint> contours)
{
    // A resultant list to return the inflection points
    List<List<Point>> result = new List<List<Point>>();

    // Calculate the forward to reverse cross product at each vertex
    List<double> crossProducts;
    // Points used to store 2D Vectors as X,Y (I,J)
    Point priorVector, forwardVector;
    foreach (VectorOfPoint contour in contours)
    {
        crossProducts = new List<double>();
        for (int p = 0; p < contour.Size; p++)
        {
            // Determine the vector to the prior to this vertex
            priorVector = p == 0 ?
            priorVector = new Point()
            {
                X = contour[p].X - contour[contour.Size - 1].X,
                Y = contour[p].Y - contour[contour.Size - 1].Y
            } :
            priorVector = new Point()
            {
                X = contour[p].X - contour[p - 1].X,
                Y = contour[p].Y - contour[p - 1].Y
            };

            // Determine the vector to the next vector
            // If this is the lst vertex, loop back to vertex 0
            forwardVector = p == contour.Size - 1 ?
            new Point()
            {
                X = contour[0].X - contour[p].X,
                Y = contour[0].Y - contour[p].Y,
            } :
            new Point()
            {
                X = contour[p + 1].X - contour[p].X,
                Y = contour[p + 1].Y - contour[p].Y,
            };

            // Calculate the cross product of the prior and forward vectors
            crossProducts.Add(forwardVector.X * priorVector.Y - forwardVector.Y * priorVector.X);
        }

        // Given the calculated cross products, detect the inflection points
        List<Point> inflectionPoints = new List<Point>();
        for (int p = 1; p < contour.Size; p++)
        {                   
            // If there is a sign change between this and the prior cross product, an inflection,
            // or change from CW to CCW bearing increments has occurred. To and from zero products
            // are ignored
            if ((crossProducts[p] > 0 && crossProducts[p-1] < 0) ||
                (crossProducts[p] < 0 && crossProducts[p-1] > 0))
            {
                inflectionPoints.Add(contour[p]);
            }
        }
        result.Add(inflectionPoints);
    }
    return result;
}
```

### Output

```
L: Baseline Inflections:0 Testcase Inflections:22
E: Baseline Inflections:1 Testcase Inflections:16
M: Baseline Inflections:4 Testcase Inflections:15
P: Baseline Inflections:11 Testcase Inflections:17
E: Baseline Inflections:1 Testcase Inflections:10
R: Baseline Inflections:9 Testcase Inflections:16
```

### Contours (Blue) and Inflections (Red)

[image: BaseLineOutput]
[image: TestCaseOutput]

Comment: This is a good idea (+1), but the implementation needs work. The letters in the first example don’t have as many inflection points as you detect, a diagonal straight line doesn’t have an inflection point at every pixel, it has 0 such points. A bit of smoothing if the vertices should take care of that, or explicitly looking for the stair-case effect of straight lines and ignoring those.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for the feedback. You've struck there on one of a few limitations to the polyline contour in that ultimately are no "curves" but only "stair-cases". What I'd like to see perhaps is a regression of the contour vertices to some bezier spline set that could be analysed for true, mathematical inflections or an alternative curvature comb method. I'll think further on a algorithmic solution to detect alternating cross product sign as per the stair-case scenario.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have added a simple re-pointing of the contours to allow for non-orthogonal vectors and to offer some level of normalization for scale/resolution. I do not include transitions to or from orthogonal vectors to be inflections, resulting in single points for the "perfect" Es. It's far from perfect, but I feel it's an improvement.

Comment: I agree, this looks good! It’s not trivial to find the right scale, of course. Nice!

Comment: Thanks! It seems so obvious now in hindsight of your first comment, but without some level of reduction and smoothing every alternate vertex will be an inflection. Thank you for driving me to think further; truly constructive criticism.